# Scilab optim function does not work

Tags: scilab, nonlinear-optimization

Can someone explain me how the optim function works in Scilab and give me a short example of that. 
What I am trying to do is to maximize this function and find the optimal value

```
> function [f, g, ind]=cost(x, ind)

    f= -x.^2

    g=2*x
endfunction

// Simplest call
x0 = [1; -1; 1];
[fopt, xopt] = optim(cost, x0)
```

When I am trying to implement the function, I receive error

> Variable returned by scilab argument function is incorrect.

I think I do some very basic mistake but can't understand where.

Comment: I'm not using scilab, but "it does not work" hardly looks like a good description of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the answer is that `-x.^2` does not return a scalar but a vector (`x` is a vector and `x.^2` is an elementwise operation). You probably want to say something like `x'*x`. The objective function of an optimization problem should always be scalar (otherwise we end up with a multi-objective or multi-criteria problem which is a whole different type of problem).
- Minimizing `-x'*x` is probably not a good idea
- The gradient is not correct for `f=-x'*x` (but see previous point).